# Compare-Object Returns nothing powershell

Tags: powershell, compare, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

So I have this two files "file1.txt" and "file2.txt" with lists, for example:

***File 1***:

Tomato

Ketchup

Mustard

***File 2:***

Tomato

Mustard

Salt

Then I need to take the lines which are only on the first file so I tried

```
Compare-Object $(Get-Content file1.txt) $(Get-Content file2.txt)
```

and it was still showing me all the lines, so I went for Property

```
Compare-Object $(Get-Content file1.txt) $(Get-Content file2.txt) -Property inputObject
```

And I got this result:

```
inputObject SideIndicator
----------- -------------
            <=
```

I'm stucked and online the only result I get from searching online is people that after adding the "-Property" filter got it right.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When I run your command I get exactly the expected result. ( Salt =>  and Ketchup  <=)

Comment: @Olaf well that is how it is supposed to work so I dont find it strange that you can do it with this command. I'm getting the lists from other commands' outputs so maybe it can be that?

Comment: when i run the Compare-Object on those two arrays, i get `Salt =>` & `Ketchup <=` as output. that is what it _should_ show. [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Im getting exactly this 

InputObject SideIndicator
----------- -------------
Mustard     =>           
Salt        =>           
Ketchup     <=           
Mustard     <=

Comment: You might have problems with invisible charachters or encodung problems .... try to recreate your files "from scratch" and run your command again.

Comment: @Olaf tried rn and yeah it seems to be working, thanks, but the inputobject propery now returns nothing

Comment: I doubt that there is a property `inputObject` of any of  compared objects as those are arrays. Try `(Compare-Object $(Get-Content file1.txt) $(Get-Content file2.txt)|Where-Object {$_.SideIndicator -eq '<='}).InputObject`.

Comment: @Spina97 - it LOOKS like your data has some stuff that aint showing - perhaps trailing spaces? you may need to clean the inputs by running `.Trim()` on each item _before_ you feed it to `Compare-Object`. ///// it's worth noting that you are NOT "howing me all the lines" in the info you just posted. the `Tomato` line is not listed ... that is a _good_ indicator that your data needs cleaning. [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey yeah we already deduced that

Comment: @JosefZ it is returning it right, I'll post it as an answer later! Thanks guys!

Comment: @Spina97 - kool! glad to know you got it working ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I had two problems (thanks to @Olaf, @Lee_Dailey and @JosefZ for their help!)

The first problem was that I was getting my data from lists made by commands, so it was a lot of blank spaces and such which were solved by running the following set of commands:

```
(gc file1.txt) | ? {$_.trim() -ne "" } | set-content file1.txt
(gc file2.txt) | ? {$_.trim() -ne "" } | set-content file2.txt

(gc file1.txt) | ? {$_.trim() -ne " " } | set-content file1.txt
(gc file2.txt) | ? {$_.trim() -ne " " } | set-content file2.txt
```

Afterwards I needed to do this (as suggested by @JosefZ) to get the correct set of results:

```
(Compare-Object $(Get-Content file1.txt) $(Get-Content file2.txt)|Where-Object {$_.SideIndicator -eq '<='}).InputObject
```

Really thankful to you three, by myself I would have never ever reached the answer!